# overloading equals equals sign return statement

Tags: c++

I want ask one simple question that I have made a class of rectangle, I know how to overload +, -, * and / but having confusion in overloading == operator, the reference says something like this

```
bool rectangle::operator==(const rectangle& Rectangle) const
{
return (length == Rectangle.length &&  width == Rectangle.width);
}
```

I didnt understood its return statement , please can anyone explain it briefly. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this overloaded operator == you return bool. Bool is a type which only can have two values:
true or false.

In this case, your function return true only if two rectangles have equals lenghts and widths.

In this statement you have two ampersands which equals to the boolean algebra `and`. So function return only true if widths and lengths are equals.

Comment: dont we have to use if statement if(length == Rectangle.length && width == Rectangle.width){return true} else {return false}????

Comment: No, because every statement with boolean algebra sign will return one of bool vaules (true/false). When you use if(..==...) the equals sign return a value which is used for if, so you can use this value in others statement.

Comment: @user3215228 No. If the value of the comparison were `true`, you'd return `true`. If it were `false`, you'd return `false`. In both cases, you'd return the value of the comparison. So you just return the value of the comparison directly, instead of complectifying things.

Comment: Yes, when the value returns from comparison in this case you must add return before it: return (...==...) to do exactly the same as your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a boolean value (true/false) as is expected from the equality operator (==).
The function compares the length & width of the lhs and rhs and returns true if both are equal

Comment: dont we have to use if statement if(length == Rectangle.length &&  width == Rectangle.width){return true} else {return false}????

Comment: It is the shortform of exactly what you pasted.